# How to catch error 500 in realtime api?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I'm getting error code 500 in the javascript console when modifying a CollaborativeString using the realtime api:

POST hxxxx://drive.google.com/otservice/save?id=1qA6DDrkUlz4BX81ReuXWgOJTN5b61LL…access_token=ya29.AHES6ZS5MsuPJConOkygYe94jez79H_A_kRByke13RT1YM3UNsQQ-9D_ 500 (Internal Server Error) api:88

But in this case the error callback is not invoked. Is there a way to catch all realtime errors in the error callback?